# saved_model.prune() in TF2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

I am trying to prune nodes of a `SavedModel` that was generated with tf.keras. The pruning script is as follows:

```
svmod = tf.saved_model.load(fn) #version 1
#svmod = tfk.experimental.load_from_saved_model(fn) #version 2
feeds = ['foo:0']
fetches = ['bar:0']
svmod2 = svmod.prune(feeds=feeds, fetches=fetches)
tf.saved_model.save(svmod2, '/tmp/saved_model/') #version 1
#tfk.experimental.export_saved_model(svmod2, '/tmp/saved_model/') #version 2
```

If I use version #1 pruning works but gives `ValueError: Expected a Trackable object for export` when saving. In version 2, there is no prune() method.

How can I prune a TF2.0 Keras SavedModel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the way you are pruning the model in version 1 is fine; according to your error message, the resulting pruned model cannot be saved because it is not "trackable", which is a necessary condition for saving a model with `tf.saved_model.save`. One way to make a trackable object is to inherit from the [`tf.Module`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Module) class, as described in the guides for [using the SavedModel format](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) and [concrete functions](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/concrete_function). Below is an example of trying to save a [`tf.function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function) object (which fails because the object is not trackable), inheriting from`tf.module`, and saving the resulting object:

(Using Python version 3.7.6, TensorFlow version 2.1.0, and NumPy version 1.18.1)

```py
import tensorflow as tf, numpy as np

# Define a random TensorFlow function and generate a reference output
conv_filter = tf.random.normal([1, 2, 4, 2], seed=1254)
@tf.function
def conv_model(x):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, conv_filter, 1, "SAME")

input_tensor = tf.ones([1, 2, 3, 4])
output_tensor = conv_model(input_tensor)
print("Original model outputs:", output_tensor, sep="\n")

# Try saving the model: it won't work because a tf.function is not trackable
export_dir = "./tmp/"
try: tf.saved_model.save(conv_model, export_dir)
except ValueError: print(
    "Can't save {} object because it's not trackable".format(type(conv_model)))

# Now define a trackable object by inheriting from the tf.Module class
class MyModule(tf.Module):
    @tf.function
    def __call__(self, x): return conv_model(x)

# Instantiate the trackable object, and call once to trace-compile a graph
module_func = MyModule()
module_func(input_tensor)
tf.saved_model.save(module_func, export_dir)

# Restore the model and verify that the outputs are consistent
restored_model = tf.saved_model.load(export_dir)
restored_output_tensor = restored_model(input_tensor)
print("Restored model outputs:", restored_output_tensor, sep="\n")
if np.array_equal(output_tensor.numpy(), restored_output_tensor.numpy()):
    print("Outputs are consistent :)")
else: print("Outputs are NOT consistent :(")
```

Console output:

```
Original model outputs:
tf.Tensor(
[[[[-2.3629642   1.2904963 ]
   [-2.3629642   1.2904963 ]
   [-0.02110204  1.3400152 ]]

  [[-2.3629642   1.2904963 ]
   [-2.3629642   1.2904963 ]
   [-0.02110204  1.3400152 ]]]], shape=(1, 2, 3, 2), dtype=float32)
Can't save <class 'tensorflow.python.eager.def_function.Function'> object
because it's not trackable
Restored model outputs:
tf.Tensor(
[[[[-2.3629642   1.2904963 ]
   [-2.3629642   1.2904963 ]
   [-0.02110204  1.3400152 ]]

  [[-2.3629642   1.2904963 ]
   [-2.3629642   1.2904963 ]
   [-0.02110204  1.3400152 ]]]], shape=(1, 2, 3, 2), dtype=float32)
Outputs are consistent :)
```

Therefore you should try modifying your code as follows:

```py
svmod = tf.saved_model.load(fn) #version 1
svmod2 = svmod.prune(feeds=['foo:0'], fetches=['bar:0'])

class Exportable(tf.Module):
    @tf.function
    def __call__(self, model_inputs): return svmod2(model_inputs)

svmod2_export = Exportable()
svmod2_export(typical_input)    # call once with typical input to trace-compile
tf.saved_model.save(svmod2_export, '/tmp/saved_model/')
```

If you don't want to inherit from `tf.Module`, you can alternatively just instantiate a `tf.Module` object and add a `tf.function` method/callable attribute by replacing that section of code as follows:

```py
to_export = tf.Module()
to_export.call = tf.function(conv_model)
to_export.call(input_tensor)
tf.saved_model.save(to_export, export_dir)

restored_module = tf.saved_model.load(export_dir)
restored_func = restored_module.call
```

Comment: this is very helpful, however I am running into an issue. My model is trainer with an estimator, which seems to input `global_step` as an input. as such, when trying to do the above, I am getting an error:

`TypeError: Expected argument names ['Placeholder', 'global_step'] but got values for ['Placeholder']. Missing: ['global_step'].`

Comment: Actually, I fixed that by manually passing a global step in the __call__ function definition. However, when trying to load, I am getting the error: ```File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saving_utils.py", line 113, in trace_model_call
    if isinstance(model.call, def_function.Function):
AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'call'```

Comment: Hmm... Can you post full code and error message? Maybe as a new answer or new question, it's hard trying to read code in a comment without line breaks

Comment: posted it here separately: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61492740/tf2-savedmodel-pruning-freezing

Answer (score 0):

As you can prune successfully in version #1 , I suggest you to try out 'pickle' to save the model.
Try the below steps to save the model.

```
import pickle
with open('<model_name.pkl>', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(<your_model>, f)
```

Read the model as:

```
with open('<model_name.pkl>', 'rb') as f:
    model = pickle.load(f)
```

In your case, for version #1, **your_model** inside the code snippet is **svmod2**.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear that I need to use the TF SavedModel format which is standard for TF serving, TFLite, etc. Saving in a pickle file doesn't accomplish this.