# Create a checkpoint for class Model(object) in Tensorflow 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I was just trying to use low level API of tensorflow2. I created my model based on this tutorial :
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training#define_the_model

Then I want to create a checkpoint for my training process, and I follow this tutorial :
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint

The problem is the checkpoint's tutorial use a class with tf.keras.Model as parameter, while I use object as my parameter. It gave me error, said that it was expecting a trackable object.

Here is the snippet of my code:

```
class SimpleANN(object):
    def __init__(self):
        initializer = tf.initializers.glorot_uniform()
        self.w1 = tf.Variable(initializer([784, 360]), name = 'weight1', trainable = True, dtype = tf.float32)
        self.w2 = tf.Variable(initializer([360, 64]), name = 'weight2', trainable = True, dtype = tf.float32)
        self.w3 = tf.Variable(initializer([64, 10]), name = 'weight3', trainable = True, dtype = tf.float32)

    def __call__(self, x, leaky_relu_alpha = 0.2):
        fc1 = tf.nn.leaky_relu(tf.matmul(x, self.w1), alpha = leaky_relu_alpha)
        fc2 = tf.nn.leaky_relu(tf.matmul(fc1, self.w2), alpha = leaky_relu_alpha)
        logits = tf.matmul(fc2, self.w3)

        return logits

model = SimpleANN() 
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate)

ckpt = tf.train.Checkpoint(step=tf.Variable(1), optimizer=optimizer, model = model)
```

then I got this error :

```
ValueError: `Checkpoint` was expecting a trackable object (an object
derived from `TrackableBase`), got <__main__.SimpleANN object at
0x000001D859792748>. If you believe this object should be trackable
(i.e. it is part of the TensorFlow Python API and manages state),
please open an issue.
```

I would like to know If it is able to implement tf.train.Checkpoint for the low level API, as what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

What you try is far less, then a tensorflow keras **Model** does.
If you really want to know, what does "low level" model creation mean, take a visit to github: [tensorflow/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py), where you will find a lot reference to of what you need to do to reach success with your approach e.g. `@trackable.no_automatic_dependency_tracking` decorator. 
As you will see there, even `Model()` class has parameters, you have to dive into.
Obviously it is not impossible, but you have to dive deeper.

Comment: thank you sir for the reference, so are you suggesting that I should use decorator as one of the way so that my program can run successfully ?

Comment: @AnthonyLauly your welcome. What I suggest you to interpret the Modul class and its parameters and figure out what it uses to get the trackable object and maybe some more other things, what we need here.

Answer (score 0):

The TensorFlow SavedModel API can only be used to save trackable objects (which Keras models are by default). One way to create a trackable object using the low-level API is to inherit from `tf.Module`. In my environment (Python version 3.7.6, TensorFlow version 2.1.0), I can make the errors go away by replacing the line `class SimpleANN(object):` with `class SimpleANN(tf.Module):`.

You may or may not also need to decorate your methods with `@tf.function`, and call them once to trace-compile a graph before saving a checkpoint. For more information, see [my answer to RobR's question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60508632/8477566).